# How do I implement a step counter into a bubble sort?

Tags: c#, sorting

I am trying to implement a *step counter* into my bubble sort algorithm, but I don't know how to *display the counter* at the end of the sorting algorithm. If anyone could explain how I should go about this that would be great. Thank You.

**My current code:** (Bubble Sort):

```
static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr, int n)
{
    int stepCount = 0; // <- Counter to return and display

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
            stepCount++;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

public static void DisplayArrayBubble(int[] arr)
{
    foreach (int i in arr)
    {
        Console.Write(i.ToString() + "  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: you could add  `Console.Write(stepCount);` before `return arr;` row

Comment: You don't need to return the array since you are sorting it in-place. So instead, you could change the return type to `int` and return `stepCount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just return `int` - number of steps? I.e.

```
// arr    : will be sorted
// return : number of steps
static int bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
  if (null == arr)
    return 0;

  int stepCount = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length - 1 - i; j++) 
      if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) {
        int temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;

        stepCount += 1;
      }

  return stepCount;
}
```

**Demo**:

```
   int[] sample = new int[] {1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7};

   int steps = bubbleSort(sample);

   Console.WriteLine($"Sorted [{string.Join(", ", sample)}] in {steps} steps");
```

**Outcome:**

```
   Sorted [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7] in 6 steps
```

Answer (score 0):

There a plethora of ways but one is to make a custom class to hold both pieces of information that you need:

```
    public class BubbleObject
    {
        public int[] arr { get; set; }
        public int stepCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Then adjust the code you have to use that object:

```
 static BubbleObject bubbleSort(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        int stepCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
            {
                if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
                {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
                stepCount++;
            }
        }

        BubbleObject bo = new BubbleObject() { arr=arr, stepCount=stepCount}

        return bo;
    }
    public static void DisplayArrayBubble(BubbleObject bo)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Number of Steps = " + bo.stepCount);

        foreach (int i in bo.arr)
        {
            Console.Write(i.ToString() + "  ");
        }
    }
```

That should do it. There are other ways as well.